# How to integrate Bokeh Server into Django

Tags: python, django, bokeh

Currently I have a Bokeh server running.
I can access it and when I push some buttons then Python code runs in the background and finally a figure is plot.

Now I need to add some things:

- I want users to authenticate.
- Users should be able to save results to a database.
- Some general data (costs, the same for everybody) should also be obtained from a database.
- User sessions should be stored.
- In the end multiple apps will be made available to users. Not all users will have access to all apps. Authentication should solve this.

So I think I should integrate the Bokeh server into Django using server_document(). However, I am not able to find a minimal working example. It would be nice if that example includes the topics from my list.

Comment: as I remember `Boken` uses web framework `Flask` to run it - so it would need to run two web servers at the same time - `Django` and `Bokeh`(`Flask`). And Django may need to use `requests` or `urllib.request` to access data from server `Boken` and use it on own pages.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integrating-bokeh-visualizations-in-django-application/amp/